# ‘le di’ meaning ‘I took’ instead of ‘I gave’ - darle un trago (a algo)

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, significado-en-contexto

> La única vez que probé cerveza fue cuando tenía doce años y le di un trago en secreto a la Old Style de apá cuando fue al baño.

This is translated by google translate as:

> The only time I ever tasted beer was when I was twelve and I secretly took a drink of Daddy's Old Style when he went to the bathroom.

I don't understand why "le di un trago" means I took a drink.  "Le di" would normally mean "I gave" (to him), not "I took".  But "I took" makes sense in this context.  This is from *Yo no soy tu perfecta hija mexicana*, written from the perspective of a 15 year old girl facing a variety of challenges.  I highly recommend this book for intermediate learners, even though it has some slang.

By the way, I tried to chop up the sentence in google translate to figure out at what point "le di" comes to mean "I took" instead of "I gave".  So, for example

> Le di un trago de cerveza de mi papá

means

> I gave him a drink of my dad's beer

But I couldn't figure out what's going on with the entire sentence I quoted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me temo que la traducción de Google es correcta. En este caso, **darle un trago (a algo)** significa tomar un poco de bebida de la lata—o puede ser de una botella, lo que fuere.

Lo más equivalente a *darle un trago* es *to take a gulp* o *to take a drink*. A veces, en algunos casos podría ser *to take a sip* (tomar un sorbo).

En general, en los idiomas se generan modismos y expresiones típicas en donde al juntarse las palabras se genera un significado diferente al que se obtendría si analizáramos cada una por separado. Lo mismo pasa en el inglés, en donde por ejemplo *get on* puede significar ‘subir a’, ‘manejar’ o ‘progresar’; pero si alguien *got on my nerves* no necesariamente significa que entró espacialmente a mi cabeza y está montado sobre mis nervios sino que me puso nervioso.

Con el tiempo se aprenden las expresiones típicas. En general el contexto es lo que más te ayuda a determinar el significado. En este caso está hablando de que probó cerveza, así que la expresión algo tiene que ver con eso. Por otra parte, un trago es el resultado de tragar. Por lo tanto, si ‘le da’ un trago a la birra, por el acto del ‘trago’ y debido al contexto dado por lo que dijo antes, el verbo ‘dar(le)’ posee en esta construcción un significado algo diferente del usual.

**Conclusión**: *to chop up* no siempre es la mejor estrategia para traducir. En realidad el problema reside en saber *dónde* cortar la oración sin que sus partes pierdan sentido. En este caso ‘le di un trago’ es un *a-tomo*, es indivisible; y, aunque uno puede ‘dar un trago de una bebida a alguien’, acá es ella misma quien ‘le da un trago a la bebida’.

Por cierto, 'dar' es uno de esos verbos que pueden traer dolores de cabeza, pues éste *se dice en muchos sentidos*. Esto es, hay un montón de significados posibles además de 'give'. Te recomiendo que lo revises en algún diccionario, las acepciones principales están entre ocho y diez.

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent explanation. My experience trying to figure this out also underlined for me the shortcomings of google translate. Sometimes it gets it right; other times not so much.  From google translate:

" Le di un trago de cerveza a la lata" ->  "I took a drink of beer from the can" (right)
"Le doy un trago de cerveza a la lata" ->  "I give a drink of beer to the can" (wrong)
"Le doy un trago de cerveza a la botella" -> "I take a drink of beer from the bottle" (right)